# Generic Class Type Parameters that I dont wanna use?

Tags: c#, class, generics, parameters, overloading

I want to show off my class declaration here:

```
class ResourceHolder<ResourceT, IdentifierT, ParameterT>
```

Therefore I have two cases where I gonna launch this class:

```
 ResourceHolder<Texture, idTextures, IntRect> mTextureHolder;
 ResourceHolder<SoundBuffer, idSounds> mSoundHolder;
```

As you can see in the latter one with the attribute **SoundBuffer** I don't really need the third parameter in any case within the class combined with type **SoundBuffer**.

So my question is how to declare the generic class so I can use both ways without getting compiler errors? How to overload that class declaration if its possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to declare those as two aeparate classes.  You *may* be able to use inheritance:

```
class ResourceHolder<ResourceT, IdentifierT, ParameterT>
{
}

class ResourceHolder<ResourceT, IdentifierT> 
    : ResourceHolder<ResourceT, IdentifierT, Object>
{
}
```

but they would still be two different types, and you'd have to overload any methods that require a `ParameterT` as an input.

Comment: ok I got u here. meanwhile I tried something else like giving the method, which actually is in need of that ParameterT and just made that method a generic one with ParameterT as Attribute parameter. that kinda worked out just as I expected. Now I dont need to declare unecassery classes which generic types I dont actually need for specific instances. thanks for ur help anyway guys !

Answer (score 0):

A C# class must have a fixed number of type parameters, so what you want isn't literally possible. You can declare a dummy type and use that as the third parameter, hiding this behind a method call, but a better approach is to reconsider what, if anything, `ResourceHolder` has as its responsibilities that means it doesn't have to do anything with `ParameterT`. It smells like you've really got two classes where you're currently using one -- you may want a `ResourceHolder` base class from which `TextureHolder` and `SoundBufferHolder` derive, for example.